# Why is my WPF listview code throwing an excpetion when programatically selecting a row

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, selection, listviewitem

I am trying to programmatically highlight the first row in a WPF listview control using VS2008 with 3.5 of the .NET framework.  Here is the C# code for this:

```
ListViewItem Val = (ListViewItem)ListView1.Items[0];
Val.IsSelected = true;
```

The code throws an exception at the first line, which is after ListView1 is populated with data.  The message in the exception says:

"Unable to cast object of type 'Message.LV1Data' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem'."

LV1Data is the class I am using to bind columns in this control.  So, it looks like it is trying to return an LV1Data object instead of a ListViewItem object.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong or what I need to do in order to programmatically highlight a listview row?

Here is the XAML code for the ListView control:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingListViewItemStyle}" AlternationCount="2" SelectionChanged="ListView1_SelectionChanged"
 SelectionMode="Multiple" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource = "{Binding ElementName=LobbyWindow, Path=ListCollection1}">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Game}">
         <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Game" FontWeight="Bold" />
         </GridViewColumn>
         <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Stakes}">
         <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Stakes" Width="68" FontWeight="Bold" />
         </GridViewColumn>
         <GridViewColumn Width="30" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Seats}">
         <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Seats" FontWeight="Bold" />
         </GridViewColumn>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**EDIT**

```
<!-- Define the resource for the alternating background background used in the ListView objects.  -->
<StackPanel.Resources>
   <Style x:Key="alternatingListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
      <Style.Resources>
         <!-- Foreground for Selected ListViewItem -->
         <!-- <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/> -->
         <!-- Background for Selected ListViewItem -->
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Brown"/>
      </Style.Resources>
      <Style.Triggers>
         <!-- setting up triggers for alternate background colors -->
         <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFD9F2BF"></Setter>
         </Trigger>
         <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
         </Trigger>
         <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
         </Trigger>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightBlue" />
         </Trigger>
         <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
               <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"></Condition>
               <Condition Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0"></Condition>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
         </MultiTrigger>
         <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
               <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"></Condition>
               <Condition Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1"></Condition>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"></Setter>
         </MultiTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
      <!-- setting row height here -->
   </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

Comment: Did you try ListView1.SelectedIndex = 0 ?

Comment: That works for just one row, but I need to be able to select multiple rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bound to an items source, which means asking for the items[x] will return a type of the data you bound to (whatever type is stored in ListCollection1).

If you want to alter it's IsSelected, you'll have to create that property on the type in ListCollection1, and bind to it in a style or template.

The IsSelected property you create will have to be implemented as a DependencyProperty, or the Type it's in will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and trigger that event when the property changes.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="...">
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Then you'll cast to that dataobject type, and set it's IsSelected value.

Find in your code the `ListCollection1`. It's definition will look like `List<Element>`. `Element` is the type you need to cast to.

Element needs to either look like

```
public class Element : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private _IsSelected;
   public Boolean IsSelected 
   { 
      get { return _IsSelected; }
      set 
      { 
          _IsSelected = value; 
          if (PropertyChanged != null) 
             PropertyChanged("IsSelected");
      }
   }    

   //snip Implement interface INotifyPropertyChanged.

   //snip your other code
}
```

*-OR-*

```
public class Element : DependencyObject
{
    public static DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelected" ...

   //snip your other code
}
```

Then your code should look like this.

```
Element Val = (Element)ListView1.Items[0];
Val.IsSelected = true;
```

Comment: In your XAML code, it is using ListBox.  Should it be ListView, or is ListBox correct?

Comment: Please forgive me for asking about this, but I tried adding the IsSelected property to the code.  It still throws an exception.  I suspect that I did not add it correctly or in the right place.  I have edited the XAML code above to include my resource and styles.  Can you tell me where the IsSelected property should be added in the XAML code?

Comment: **Stop casting to a ListViewItem!!!** Create an object with an IsSelectedProperty, put that in the ListView, and cast to that when you want to set "IsSelected".

Comment: If you still have difficulty. Then refer to [Justin's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15841289/491837) answer.

Comment: Note: This only works one way, from the datavalue to the IsSelected property on the ListViewItem.

Answer (score 1):

Items is bound to your business object, so that is why it is not actually returning a listview item. You can try three things:

[Use SetSelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.setselecteditems.aspx) and only pass in an `IEnumerable` of one object

OR, you can get the object and then ask for the `ListViewItem` it refers to

```
(ListViewItem)ListView1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(ListView1.Items[0])
```

OR, you can bind to the `IsSelected` property and manage that in your viewmodel

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I tried using the code from your 2nd suggestion, but it returned null.  I don't know how to use the SetSelectedItems, since the link is for a listbox, not a ListView and I don't see a SetSelectedItems method for the ListView class.  I also tried binding to the IsSelected property, but it does not seem to be working either.  I have edited my code to show where I added the IsSelected property to my XAML.  Did I do this correctly?